# Adding default values to settings.bundle items?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have noticed that some values in settings.bundle (Root.plist) do not allow you to associate a default value with them?

[image]

Is there a way to add a default field or is it simply a case of adding the appropriate defaults for these items inside the application using ...

```
NSDictionary *defaultSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Kinetic", @"IDBombs", nil];
[userDefaults registerDefaults:defaultSettings];
```

Just curious if I am doing this right or missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right mouse click on any row within the item, click `Add row` on the menu and choose `Default value`.

Comment: That's what we are here for :)